# How to update database from angularjs with spring?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to update database using angularjs and spring.
Bellow code i was using but it is not working.
**app.js**

```
$scope.updateUserInformation=function updateUserInformation(){

     alert("hai");

     $http.post(urlBase+'/angular/edit/',{student:$scope.student}).success(function (data){

         alert("Update Successfull");
     });


 }
```

**Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/angular/edit/",method=RequestMethod.POST,params="{student}")
        public String updateUser(@RequestParam("student") Angular an) throws ParseException{

          String name=an.getUserame();
          ts.updateUser(an);
          return "AngularData";




      }
```

**jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html ng-app="taskManagerApp">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>AngularJS Task Manager</title>

<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/app.js"/>"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-controller="taskManagerController">



   <span>Add Task</span>


  <div>

   <div>

    <table>

     <tr>

      <td> Name:</td>

      <td><input type="text" ng-model="student.Name"/></td>

     </tr>

     <tr>

      <td>City:</td>

      <td><input type="text" ng-model="student.City"/></td>

     </tr>


     <tr>

      <td>

<button ng-click="addTask()" class="btn-panel-big">Add New Task</button></td>

<td><button ng-click="updateUserInformation()" class="btn-panel-big">Update User</button></td>

     </tr>

    </table>        

   </div>

  </div>


  <div>
  <table>
     <div>

     <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
     <td>  {{user.id}}</td>
     <td> {{user.userame}}</td>
     <td> {{user.city}}</td>
     <td><button  ng-click="updateUser(user)" class="btn-panel-big">Edit</button></td></td>
     </tr>

     </div>
  </table>

  </div>


  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I try to set the scope variable like  `$scope.student.Name=user.userame;` even it is not working.how can i set the scope variable.

using the above program i try to update the database table but controller is not getting parameter can any one help me to fix this

Comment: what is the error on console?

Comment: You're sending JSON object as the body of the request on the angular side. So you need to get the JSON out of the body of the request on the spring side: `@RequestMapping(value="/angular/edit/",method=RequestMethod.POST") public String updateUser(@RequestBody SomePojoMappedToYourJSONUsingJackson command)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.updateUserInformation=function updateUserInformation(){

     alert("hai");

     $http.post(urlBase+'/angular/edit/',$scope.student).success(function (data){

         alert("Update Successfull");
     });
}
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/angular/edit/",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String updateUser(@RequestBody Angular an) throws ParseException{

          String name=an.getUserame();
          ts.updateUser(an);
          return "AngularData";
}
```

Comment: Make sure in `Angular` class you have `Name` and `City` Attributes for mapping, because you have take `ng-model="student.Name"` so..

Comment: It's working fine.another thing i want to know how to set scope variable value like $scope.student.Name=data.userame;

Comment: If object have same name attributes it will automatically mapped other wise you have to do manually like `$scope.student.Name=data.userame;`..

Comment: objects are having same name while getting the values from db and display that into that text box how can i set the value to scope

Comment: just pass data to student object, `$scope.student = data;` so it will automatically set value of `$scope.student.Name` using `ng-model`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149363/discussion-between-hrdkisback-and-kvk).

Comment: please check the chat

Comment: question is about update database so why using post instead of put request.